# Whenever I press Shift + Z to Undo my errors It just goes into frame mode why does it do that?

Tags: shortcut

Whenever I press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> to undo my error, it just puts me into wireframe mode. I wanna undo my errors, but it doesn't work as I excepted.

Comment: By default Shift+Z should activate Rendered shading mode, not Wireframe. Ctrl+Z as already mentioned is for undo, Ctrl+Alt+Z for undo history

Answer (score 5):

The shortcut for undo is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd> not <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>.